# Why is my curl request showing a different result than the browser?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

My php Curl request(also curl command in terminal) unfortunately shows a different code than opening the URL manually in the browser.

Here is my problem: I want to display the currently available films from https://reservierung.kinolambach.at/filmlist/?location_id=1 (german cinema)
on my website. When you check your network tab, the website sends an ajax call to a url with the specific date to the server and gets a response. Try it out by calling https://reservierung.kinolambach.at/filmlist/?location_id=1&date=4.1.2021&film_table=true in your browser(due to Covid there is a test film available on 4. Jan 2021)

My website **does not run on the same domain**.

Using an ajax call did not work because of CORS-Policy, so my second approach is to load the data via curl from php.

Here is my php code, which does not work. For every request I make I get the result "No film available on this day". It seems as if "No film available on this day" (german: 'Für diesen Tag ist kein Programm verfügbar.') is the "default" response.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://reservierung.kinolambach.at/filmlist/?location_id=1&date=4.1.2021&film_table=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

There are several `curl_setopt` which I tried out, none did work.

**Here is my question**
How is it possible, that curl shows a different result than calling the url in the browser? You can even try it in your terminal with `curl https://reservierung.kinolambach.at/filmlist/?location_id=1&date=1.1.2021&film_table=true`
How can I change this? I guess it has to do with the header.

Thanks in advance and all the best!

Comment: I get `Für diesen Tag ist kein Programm verfügbar.` even if I click on the link you provided (in my browser).

Comment: Something weird on server side. First request via browser I get default message as IVO GELOV, but at second request, I get requested list and for following requests aswell. With more testing - problem is cookie sessionid, without it you get only default response.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://reservierung.kinolambach.at/filmlist/?
location_id=1&date=4.1.2021&film_table=true');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'C:/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Works form me with cookies enabled. On second request as my comment before.

Comment: yeah it's a cookie issue, but there's no need to hardcode a cookie path here, just set CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to emptystring, and the cookies will be stored in-ram together with the curl handle; also don't hardcode `C:/tmp/` , that code will break when running on any non-windows OS (like say, MacOS or Linux), instead use [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php), that's a portable solution working on Windows, Linux, and MacOS alike

Comment: i think you should clarify that OP needs to run curl_exec($ch); twice, and only the 2nd response will contain the list